# 410 response code in subdirectory

Tags: htaccess

I have an htaccess file in one of my subdirectories. I'm trying to throw a 410 response code for `.doc` and `.pdf` files in my uploads directory for my multisite installation.

So my `.htaccess` file is in this directory: `wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016`

and looks like this:

```
RedirectMatch gone "/01/\.pdf$"
```

So shouldn't this throw a 410 for the following URL:

```
wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/01/my-file.pdf
```

The full url is currently returning a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RedirectMatch gone "/01/\.pdf$"
> ```

This would match URLs that end in `/01/.pdf`, so won't match the given URL that ends `/01/my-file.pdf`.

However, it may be preferable to use mod_rewrite in order to override the standard WordPress directives in the root of the site.

Try the following instead to send a 410 Gone for all `.doc` and `.pdf` files in the directory (`.htaccess` file should be the appropriate subdirectory):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \.(doc|pdf)$ - [G]
```

**UPDATE:** If you are still getting a 404 for these resources (which don't exist) then it's possible that you have a custom error document that overrides the HTTP status code. Try resetting this by adding the following before the above directives:

```
ErrorDocument 410 default
```

Comment: I placed a .htaccess file in the: wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/01/ directory but I'm still not getting a 410. I continue to receive a 404 for any files that used to exist in the directory.

Comment: What 404 error document is returned? WordPress 404, Apache custom or default document? It's possible you have a defined error document that is overriding the HTTP status? I've updated my answer.